# Seamless SVG Animation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to make a seamless animation so teh svg just continues to act like rain in a continous loop. The problem is the animation resets and you can tell. I would like to do this with CSS3 animations. Is the possible?

Full code is in codepen below

```
#sprinkles                                                  { position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; }
#sprinkles .sprinkle                                        { animation:rainSprinkles .85s linear infinite }
#sprinkles .sprinkle.white                                  { fill:$white; }
#sprinkles .sprinkle.blue                                   { fill:$blue; }
#sprinkles .sprinkle.yellow                                 { fill:$yellow; }
#sprinkles .sprinkle.pink                                   { fill:$hot-pink; }

@keyframes rainSprinkles {
    0% {

              transform: translateY(-100%);
    }

    100% {
      visibility: hidden;

              transform: translateY(1000%);
    }
}
```

Codepen Below:
http://codepen.io/Jesders88/pen/bBYQom

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to make your sprinkles be taller than the screen. Now when you move them down more come onto the screen.

[Here's a demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/s4yhz6xt/)

I've made one change from your example. Instead of having four identical squares of sprinkles, I've taken just one of the four and turned it into a pattern  That way the SVG repeats it for you and you can fill any area you want with a continuous pattern of sprinkles.

Then I have made a rectangle that is as wide as the screen and has a height equal to (svgHeight + patternHeight). I start it at -patternHeight off the top of the screen, then animate it down the distance of one patternHeight (487).

```
#rainRect {
  animation: rainSprinkles 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rainSprinkles {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(487px);
  }
}
```

We move it one patternHeight exactly so that it appears continuous when it jumps back up again to start another loop of the animation.

Comment: That's cool. The only problem is that when I try to set another animation to the individual sprinkles, it spins the whole box. I was envisioning having all of the sprinkles fall at different speeds and they rotate and scale at the same time. I guess my question is, is there a way around rotating the whole box in the pattern?

Comment: I tried adding another animation to the individual sprinkles. I wanted to translate them down all at different speeds. I got it working, but you can tell wehre the pattern ends. The bottom of the square was apparent. I guess  If I change the animation is not smooth again. http://codepen.io/Jesders88/pen/bBYQom?editors=1100

Comment: If you want to do that, then you won't really be able to use a pattern.  You will need to go back to having a giant object with every sprinkle defined.

Comment: That takes me back to my original problem then. The sprinkles will fall at different rates but you still get that jumpy effect when the animation starts again. Do I just need to place the position of the SVG off screen again? Any help is appreciated here. I can't figure out how to loop the SVG without getting that jumpy effect or having the sprinkles go off the screen before starting over again. Do you have an example or could you help me out in my codepen?

Comment: One way is to just to do what I've already done, except split your SVG into two or more layers.  Then apply the same animation to each layer with differing durations.